# Leave current function via exception in called function

Tags: c#, exception

Lets say I have this two functions:

```
 private string otherString;
 private void Error(string message) {
     throw new Exception("Error: " + message);
 }
 private void Expected(string message) {
     Error("Expected " + message + " got " + otherString);
 }
```

Now I want to write code that looks like the this:

```
 private int ReadInt() {
     int result = 0; 
     if(int.TryParse(otherString, out result)) {
         return result;
     }
     Expected("Int");
     //return 0; is need to compile but it will be never reached
 }
```

I understand that the compiler can not assume that by calling Expected the ReadInt function will end. Is there another way to do what I want to do without the need to write the throw statement in every place I want to exit with an Error?

```
throw new Exception("Error: Expected Digit got " + otherString);
```

Comment: what's wrong with writing `throw` when you need notify failure ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you are going to log/catch this exception later, here is the problem, With the current set up you will not know *(directly)* where the exception actually happened, from `TargetSite` you will only get information about method `Error` throwing exception and not the actual method `ReadInt`. *(Although through Stack Trace you can see the call hierarchy and the `ReadInt` method)*.

Throw exception where ever you think it should be thrown, not from some *generic* method. Also instead of throwing base class exception, throw specific exceptions like `InvalidArgumentException` etc.

**As a side note**, if you are only concerned about parsing related exceptions then don't use `TryParse` group of methods and let the original exception bubble up.

Comment: I will create an ExpectedException that takes the message and otherString to get the same error message. This is for an Lexer so I cant use the Parse Exceptions for all possible tokens.

Comment: @Habib, stacktrace will contain information about `ReadInt` method, and line number where `Expected` was invoked, so what is happened will be pretty clear. But I agreed that throwing exception in place is more descriptive

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev, you are right, I modified the answer to clarify that.

Comment: It's simplest if the exception is thrown where it occurs.  The first entry in the stack trace will then always be where the error occurred, taking you to the place in your code with the problem.  Throwing it anywhere else means you have to remember it wasn't thrown there.  It's even worse if someone else has to modify the code & doesn't know that the place where the exception was thrown is NOT the place where the problem exists!  The information may be in the stack trace, but how about making it easier on the next guy?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what the other answers are saying (don't do that, it's not a good practice), you could simply "fool" the compiler by having the error-method return a fake value:

```
private string otherString;
 private T Error<T>(string message) {
     throw new Exception("Error: " + message);
     return default(T);
 }
 private T Expected<T>(string message) {
     return Error<T>("Expected " + message + " got " + otherString);
 }

private int ReadInt() {
     int result = 0; 
     if(int.TryParse(otherString, out result)) {
         return result;
     }
     return Expected<int>("Int");
 }
```

Another possibility (as suggested in the comments) is to return the exception and throw it in the method:

```
private string otherString;
 private Exception Error(string message) {
     return new Exception("Error: " + message);
 }
 private Expected(string message) {
     return Error("Expected " + message + " got " + otherString);
 }

private int ReadInt() {
     int result = 0; 
     if(int.TryParse(otherString, out result)) {
         return result;
     }
     throw Expected("Int");
 }
```

Last, but not least, you can create your own exception and throw that one:

```
class ExpectedException : Exception
{
    public ExpectedException(string message)
       : base("Expected " + message + " got " + otherString)
    {}
}

private int ReadInt() {
     int result = 0; 
     if(int.TryParse(otherString, out result)) {
         return result;
     }
     throw new ExpectedException("Int");
 }
```

Comment: I don't think this is good practice.  Throwing exceptions to signal an error condition is vastly better than returning an error value, a la C style coding.

Comment: Not my downvote, but how would the `return default(T);` statement executes, if you are throwing the exception just before that.

Comment: Was going to suggest something similar so +1 from me, though it still feels awkward and not a good practice in general. :)

Comment: This does exactly what I want. But I will go with creating an ExpectedException that takes a message and the otherString.

Comment: See my first line "don't do that, it's not a good practice". I'm just answering the question on how he could circumvent the problem. The `default(T)` would never execute, but at least he only has to do it in one place. It's a workaround/hack for a problem that shouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: @Kenneth, you could also define `Excepted` and `Error` as a methods that return `Exception` and use them like this `throw Expected("Int")` :) This eliminates need of `default(T)`

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev Yes, I actually like that solution better, I'll update my answer

Comment: Not only isn't this good practice, you're making maintaining the code harder than it has to be.  Throw the exception where it occurs and you can rely on the first line in the stack trace to be the place where the error occurred.  Makes maintaining the code a lot easier.